# Why do JComboBox and ComboBoxModel Classes not have a List or Collection constructor?

Tags: java, swing

I know this may be opinion based but it serves to answer the follow-up question:

Vector has a constructor for any Collection so why would JComboBox and associated classes make use of just Vector? Is it okay to subclass the DefaultComboBoxModel to take advantage of a wider range of initialization types?

```
private class MyComboBoxModel<E> extends DefaultComboBoxModel<E> {
    private MyComboBoxModel (Collection<E> input) {
        super(new Vector<E>(input));
    }
}
```

Or should I just use the DefaultComboBoxModel and create a vector before calling the constructor?

```
Vector<Contact> vectorList = new Vector<Contact>(getList());
DefaultComboBoxModel<Contact> myModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel<Contact>(vectorList);
```

Comment: Collections are younger than Swing :-)

Comment: Why wouldn't they change the constructors to accept broader inputs?

Comment: Ask again after _you_ have had to fix a lot of broken code.

Comment: Another alternative assuming you already have a collection that implements the `List` interface is to call the `toArray()` method. This will give you an `Object[]` that you can use with the `DefaultComboBoxModel(Object[] items)` constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like functionality for Collections will be added in the future. From ListModel, superinterface of ComboBoxModel:

> This class loosely implements the java.util.Vector API, in that it
>   implements the 1.1.x version of java.util.Vector, has no collection
>   class support, and notifies the ListDataListeners when changes occur.
>   Presently it delegates to a Vector, in a future release it will be a
>   real Collection implementation.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html

Comment: well, it's on their todo list since ages :-)